# Meteor :read Session keys and be reactive

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor helper that is not reactive.
How do I detect that a new key has been added to Session so my helper will rerun ?

```
  'sessions': function() { // FIXME: not reactive
    return _.keys(Session.keys).sort();
  }
```

Thanks ! :)

**Edit**: I know that Session itself is reactive. But the keys of the Session dictionary is not. I would like to be able to detect that a new Session key has been added.

Comment: `Session.keys` returns the keys only. `_.keys` won't work in this case. And template helpers & `Session` is by default reactive.

Comment: Thank you. I think you misread my question. Session itself is reactive. The keys of the Session dictionary is not. I would like to be able to detect that a new Session key has been added.

Comment: You could try and overload (by monkey-patching) your `ReactiveDict`'s `set()` method  (Session is an instance of ReactiveDict) and have it invalidate a certain `Tracker` computation and depend on that computation in your helper. You can find more information about it in the [Tracker Manual](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Tracker-Manual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `Tracker`.

The `Session` is an instance of `ReactiveDict`, and does not have a way of "subscribing" to all of the keys.

Implementing this involves overriding the original `set()` method by monkey-patching.

One way of doing this is by creating a Tracker dependency for the entire dict and invalidating it every time a key is set:

```js
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import { Session } from 'meteor/session';

const originalSet = Session.set;
Session.keyDependendy = new Tracker.Dependency();

Session.set = function() {
  originalSet.apply(this, arguments);
  this.keyDependendy.changed();
}

// in your helper
'sessions': function() {
  Session.keyDependendy.depend();
  return _.keys(Session.keys).sort();
}
```

You can also make it more general by patching `ReactiveDict`'s prototype.

Comment: I believe the above will not only trigger the tracker for new keys but for changes to existing keys since both go through `.set()`

Comment: That is correct. If you want to trigger on new keys only you need to invalidate the dependency only if `typeof this.keys[key] === 'undefined'` or something similar, where `key` should be added as first argument of `set()`.